# Cannot import data file into SQL Server using BCP. How can I make this work?

Tags: sql-server, bcp, data-import

I have been trying for hours to load a data file into SQL Server using BCP but can't make it work.

This is the commando I am running: `bcp EDW.stg.STG_ACCOUNT in .\dm_account000 -T -S 111.1.1.111,1111 -t "," -c` and all I got was this error:

```
Starting copy...
SQLState = 22005, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]Invalid character value for cast specification
```

I already checked the date conversion problem that is mentioned on many websites but nothing seems to be wrong with my last three fields in the data file. Here is my data file and at the footer you can see the encoding, etc.

[image]

And here is the spec of my target table:

```
CREATE TABLE [stg].[STG_ACCOUNT](
    [CD_ACCOUNT] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [CD_CNPJ] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [NA_ACCOUNT] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [NA_OWNER] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [NA_OWNER_SHARED] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [NA_OWNER_GROWTH_TEAM] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [DS_INDUSTRY] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [DS_ACCOUNT_STATUS] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [NA_ACCOUNT_CITY] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [AB_ACCOUNT_STATE] [char](30) NULL,
    [DS_REGION] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [IN_CLASSIFICATION_PARTNER] [int] NULL,
    [IN_CLASSIFICATION_PARTNER_N] [int] NULL,
    [DS_COMPETITOR_PARTNER] [char](3) NULL,
    [DS_HEADQUARTER_BRANCH] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [DS_CHAIN_FRANCHISE] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [DS_ECONOMIC_GROUP] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [DS_WATCH_LIST] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [IN_STRATEGIC] [int] NULL,
    [DT_CREATED] [date] NULL,
    [DT_LAST_ACTIVITY] [date] NULL,
    [DT_LAST_MODIFIED] [date] NULL,
)
```

Can anybody help me with this issue? I don't really know what else I can try. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The error msg might be a bit misleading, maybe the problem is that by using -c you are setting the default row terminator to '\r\n' (CRLF) but in your file is '\n' (LF); try overriding the row separator by explicitly including -r "\r\n"

Comment: I would guess you need to specify `-t , -r \n`, seeing as you mean to have comma separators and `LF` newlines. See [Specify Field and Row Terminators (SQL Server)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191485.aspx)

Comment: @Jayvee Thanks for the answer. When I changed the EOL to 'DOS/Windows' on my datafile it worked, but there is something strange. My datafile has 125.616 lines but only 47.169 are imported. I redirected error lines to an error file but it only shows me 10 lines (that can be manually imported. There is nothing wrong with them). It seems like bcp is skipping blocks of data when an error occurs. Have you seen this behavior?

Comment: Have you checked line 47169 and 47170 to see if there is something different in them?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding -C ACP to specify the code page.

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx)...

> -C { ACP | OEM | RAW | code_page } Specifies the code page of the data in the data file. code_page is relevant only if the data contains
>   char, varchar, or text columns with character values greater than 127
>   or less than 32. System_CAPS_ICON_note.jpg Note
>
> We recommend specifying a collation name for each column in a format
>   file, except when you want the 65001 option to have priority over the
>   collation/code page specification. Code page value    Description
>   ACP   ANSI/Microsoft Windows (ISO 1252). OEM  Default code page used by
>   the client. This is the default code page used if -C is not specified.
>   RAW   No conversion from one code page to another occurs. This is the
>   fastest option because no conversion occurs. code_page    Specific code
>   page number; for example, 850.
>
> Versions prior to version 13 (SQL Server 2016) do not support code
>   page 65001 (UTF-8 encoding). Versions beginning with 13 can import
>   UTF-8 encoding to earlier versions of SQL Server.